# Select the value of a cell in GridView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to select a value in a Grid view cell on aspx page.
I need the VB.NET code to do this

In C# code will be this:

```
string id = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text
```

Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried some coding that visual studio suggest and this do the thing I wanted:

```
Dim id As string = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(1).Text
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use this page other time.
http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

```
Dim id As String = GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Text
```

Comment: e.RowIndex 
there no such property RowIndex for e